# How to disable internet in a centos VM instance created using openstack?

Tags: networking, centos, virtual-machine, openstack

In a centos Virtual machine instance that is created using openstack, how can i disable the internet?
I need only internet to be disabled but not the network. Because this VM should be able to communicate to other VM's of the same network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modified security-group, which allows only access to the local network. Per default the security-group allows all outgoing connections. These rules have to be replaced to limit them to the local network.

Example:

```
# create new security group
openstack security group create test-group
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field           | Value                                                                                                                                                 |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| created_at      | 2020-06-24T20:20:38Z                                                                                                                                  |
| description     | test-group                                                                                                                                            |
| id              | a39ac981-6547-4ed3-a2da-7037e50ef00e                                                                                                                  |
| name            | test-group                                                                                                                                            |
| project_id      | b9105cd288f740fcaec03d42fd93607e                                                                                                                      |
| revision_number | 2                                                                                                                                                     |
| rules           | created_at='2020-06-24T20:20:38Z', direction='egress', ethertype='IPv6', id='5439255a-3a7d-4f54-967d-6393622f7777', updated_at='2020-06-24T20:20:38Z' |
|                 | created_at='2020-06-24T20:20:38Z', direction='egress', ethertype='IPv4', id='6fe86a1b-47e4-4927-9533-92b9b1b8c50b', updated_at='2020-06-24T20:20:38Z' |
| updated_at      | 2020-06-24T20:20:38Z                                                                                                                                  |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# list all rules. The only shown are the two default egress-rules
openstack security group rule list test-group
+--------------------------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+
| ID                                   | IP Protocol | IP Range | Port Range | Remote Security Group |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 5439255a-3a7d-4f54-967d-6393622f7777 | None        | None     |            | None                  |
| 6fe86a1b-47e4-4927-9533-92b9b1b8c50b | None        | None     |            | None                  |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+

# delete the two rules
openstack security group rule delete 5439255a-3a7d-4f54-967d-6393622f7777 6fe86a1b-47e4-4927-9533-92b9b1b8c50b

# set the new egress-rule, which allows only communication within your local network
openstack security group rule create --egress --remote-ip 192.168.20.0/24  test-group
```

Of course you have to replace the `192.168.20.0/24` of the example by the subnet-range of your internal network, where your other VMs are connected too. Add ingress-rules like ISMP, SSH etc., if necessary and use this as only security-group for your virtual machine. With this your VMs can onyl connect to other VMs in your local network, but not to the internet anymore.